# error tried to access method sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl

Tags: java, spring, jwt, rsa

Hi I try to execute my Spring application with dependency of JWT package and I found this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>([B)V from class com.agospass.OAuth2ResourceServerConfig
    at com.agospass.OAuth2ResourceServerConfig.accessTokenConverter(OAuth2ResourceServerConfig.java:87)
    at com.agospass.OAuth2ResourceServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9e14628.CGLIB$accessTokenConverter$3(<generated>)
    at com.agospass.OAuth2ResourceServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9e14628$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e622f9ed.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.agospass.OAuth2ResourceServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9e14628.accessTokenConverter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

My jdk version 8u241 and Maven 3.8.1

someone who can help me solve this problem or replace the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public class IllegalAccessError extends IncompatibleClassChangeError
> ```
>
> Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field, or to
> call a method that it does not have access to. Normally, this error is
> caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the
> definition of a class has incompatibly changed.
> [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html)
>
> **Edited:** For JDK 11
> https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html

Certainly, your class `OAuth2ResourceServerConfig`'s method `accessTokenConverter` is trying to invoke the method from a different class available in different jar than one it compile with. This behaviour is often seen when the same class (with same package) is present in different jars with difference in the accessibility of fields/methods.

To put it simply, one can say that at compile time your code has access to public method of class available in `jar one` but at runtime, thanks to classloader, your code is trying to access the private method of same class available in `jar two`.

You can look for `RSAPublicKeyImpl` class inside the dependencies present on the classpath and update/adjust the dependencies accordingly to get rid of the issue.

Comment: I saw that it is not compatible with jdk11, so if i were to use jdk11 should i change dependency or do a refactoring? thanks

Comment: But you've originally mentioned `My jdk version 8u241 and Maven 3.8.1` in the question.

Comment: Anyways, you've to fix the dependencies.